# Match middle minimum value in set that has more than one minimum value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Let's say I have column A and B, I want to find minimum value in column B and get the corresponding value from column A. I'm using `INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(MIN(B1:B10),B1:B10,0)`. But it only works for the first minimum value in the column and I'd like if there is more than one of the same minimum value in the column to get the value from A column for the middle one in B column. Can anyone help with this problem? I'd be very grateful.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following (and adjust the logic for finding the "middle one: if what I did doesn't do the trick you desire:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A1:A9,B1:B9=MIN(B1:B9)),ROUNDUP(COUNT(FILTER(A1:A9,B1:B9=MIN(B1:B9)))/2,0))
```

Basically, it finds the miniimum value in column B. Then it filters column A for cells (could be rows if desired, for instance, in a more complex situation) for which the corresponding value in column B matches the minimum found earlier.

It then counts them, divides by two, and rounds UP the result. So three matches goes 3, 3/2 = 1.5, 1/5 —> 2, so the second one of the three cells has the value desired. For even numbers of rows, it would be the first of the two possibles (so 6 rows, rows 3 and 4 are equally "middle ones", it will return row 3, not row 4). If you actually only ever have three rows, it'll do just fine and have room for life to become more complex.

After finding which of the cells it wants, it uses `INDEX()` on the filtered part of the formula picking the cell whose index is 2.

You could add `LET()` to make it more readable, perhaps like so:

```
=LET(Possibles,FILTER(A1:A9,B1:B9=MIN(B1:B9)),INDEX(Possibles,ROUNDUP(COUNT(Possibles)/2,0)))
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!